# How to join and explode dataframes by multiple IDs using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have two dataframes and I would like to perform a join with multiple IDs.

In `df1` I have the column `KeyWordGroupID` with multiple IDs. These IDs can also be found in `df2`.

If there is a match the result dataframe with the column `KeyWordGroupName` of `df2` is splitted into new columns containing the values of `KeyWords`.

```
# initialize list of lists
data = [[0, 'Standard1', [100, 101, 102]], [1, 'Standard2', [100, 102]], [2, 'Standard3', [103]]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['RuleSetID', 'RuleSetName', 'KeyWordGroupID'])
df1

Output:

    RuleSetID   RuleSetName   KeyWordGroupID
     0           Standard1    [100, 101, 102]
     1           Standard2    [100, 102]
     2           Standard3    [103]
```

The second dataframe is:

```
# initialize list of lists
data = [[100, 'verahren', ['word1, word2']], 
        [101, 'flaechen', ['word3']], 
        [102, 'nutzung', ['word4, word5']],
        [103, 'ort', ['word6, word7']]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['KeyWordGroupID', 'KeyWordGroupName', 'KeyWords'])
df2

Output:

KeyWordGroupID  KeyWordGroupName    KeyWords
100                 verahren         [word1, word2]
101                 flaechen         [word3]
102                 nutzung          [word4, word5]
103                 ort              [word6, word7]
```

The desired output is:

```
    RuleSetID   RuleSetName   KeyWordGroupID    verfahren        flaechen    nutzung        ort 
     0           Standard1    [100, 101, 102]   [word1, word2]   [word3]     [word4, word5] None 
     1           Standard2    [100, 102]        [word1, word2]   None        [word4, word5] None
     2           Standard3    [103]             None             None        None           [word6, word7]
```

Any hint how to perform a join like this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This one is a little tricky, but here's on approach.  It takes advantage of `explode`   to make the merge possible, and `pivot` which is what this ultimately is.  Then to get rid of the empty lists it uses `applymap`

```
data = [[0, 'Standard1', [100, 101, 102]], [1, 'Standard2', [100, 102]], [2, 'Standard3', [103]]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['RuleSetID', 'RuleSetName', 'KeyWordGroupID'])

data = [[100, 'verahren', ['word1, word2']], 
        [101, 'flaechen', ['word3']], 
        [102, 'nutzung', ['word4, word5']],
        [103, 'ort', ['word6, word7']]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['KeyWordGroupID', 'KeyWordGroupName', 'KeyWords'])


(
    df1.explode('KeyWordGroupID')
       .merge(df2, on='KeyWordGroupID')
       .pivot(index=['RuleSetID','RuleSetName','KeyWordGroupID'], columns='KeyWordGroupName',values='KeyWords')
       .reset_index()
       .groupby(['RuleSetID','RuleSetName'])
       .agg(lambda x: list(x) if x.name=='KeyWordGroupID' else x.dropna())
       .applymap(lambda x: np.nan if len(x)==0 else x)
       .reset_index()
)
```

Comment: It works with the sample provided but when using it with my real dataset I am receiving an error: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape. Do you have an idea why this is happening? I added two images in my original post.

Comment: The error appears inside of the pivot function.

Comment: @Daniel, it looks like that values in `df2["KeyWordGroupName"]` are not unique. May be you could update you example data.

Comment: Hmm, Verfahrensinformation, Flächeninformation, Nutzungsinformation and Ort are unique.